# Setting CSS styles on images in Thymeleaf

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm  developing a web app using Spring MVC and Thymeleaf as templating technology. I can't understand how to set up rules to an image, possibly in an external CSS file.

I know the following code works:

**page.html**

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
  <img src="../resources/images/logo.png" class="img-responsive" />           
</a>
```

**style.css**

```
.navbar-brand > img {
    max-height: 100%;
}

h1 { text-align:center; }
```

But in this case, because I'm using Thymeleaf, my html is the following:

**thymeleaf.html**

```
[Boostrap navbar...]
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
  <img th:src="@{/resources/images/logo.png}" class="img-responsive" />            
</a>
[...]
[/Bootstrap navbar]

<h1>Test</h1>
```

and using the same CSS the rule is not applied to the image, instead I can see the rule setted on h1 (Test is centered).

**EDIT:** Rules setted on the content div within the Bootstrap navbar are not interpreted (can't see them when click on "inspect element"). Other rules, set to a normal div (without Bootstrap class or others), are interpreted correctly.

**EDIT2:** CSS import

in **servlet.xml**

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>
```

in **thymeleaf.html**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"  
      href="/resources/css/style.css" th:href="@{/resources/css/style.css}" />
```

How could I solve? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

can you add th:class ie

```
<a th:class="navbar-brand" href="#">
  <img th:src="@{/resources/images/logo.png}" th:class="img-responsive" />            
</a>
```

and let me know if this worked for you

Comment: unfortunately doesn't work; every rule I try to set on the bootstrap navbar seems to have no effect: clicking "inspects element" I can't find rules written in CSS, if I add them manually in this window, however, of course it works. I think the problem is the integration with Bootstrap, because outside of the navbar, inside any div, rules are interpreted correctly

Comment: How do you try to import the css file?